# What is the earliest statement that the world is to exist for six thousand years?

Tags: prophecies, messianism

I have seen various versions of this idea:

> The world is to exist six thousand years.
> In the first two thousand there was desolation [no Torah];
> two thousand years the Torah flourished;
> and the next two thousand years is the Messianic era,
> but through our many iniquities all these years have been lost.

What is the oldest recorded instance of this idea that there would be three, two thousand year long, ages?

Comment: Sanhedrin 97a - תנא דבי אליהו ששת אלפים שנה הוי עלמא שני אלפים תוהו שני אלפים תורה שני אלפים ימות המשיח

Comment: Translation - The school of Eliyahu taught: Six thousand years is the duration of the world. Two thousand of the six thousand years are characterized by chaos; two thousand years are characterized by Torah, from the era of the Patriarchs until the end of the mishnaic period; and two thousand years are the period of the coming of the Messiah.

Comment: @Chatzkel, I believe that was written about 1500 years ago, but it refers to it as something taught by "the school of Eliyahu", implying the idea is older than that.  Assuming the reference is to the famous prophet, it's another 1300 years or so older.  I'm looking for the *oldest explicit statement* of this idea of the three eras.  I'm particularly interested in anything predating Christianity.

Comment: @raybutterworth being that the Talmud was written when only the written Torah and the Mishnah (and braisos) were allowed to written down, I’d be surprised if there’s an earlier explicit written source. I might be wrong though. The zohar brings it as well (if that was written during R Shimon lifetime then it would be an earlier source)

Comment: It should be noted that attribution to Elijah is not necessarily an indication of the teaching's antiquity. I'm being lazy here, but see the wiki article on Tanna Devei Eliyahu https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanna_Devei_Eliyahu

Comment: @Derdeer but this particular quote is not from the Tanna Devei Eliyahu midrash but from the Talmud...

Comment: Read the whole article, it quotes Ketubot 106a

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading the whole Sugya in Sanhedrin https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.97b.3?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi, as many alternative propositions are presented, each of equal probability. The 6K theory is the most elegant, echoing the metaphor of a millennium against God's day "כי אלף שנים בעיניך כיום אתמול כי יעבר"

Comment: @Derdeer I saw that...doesn't contradict that what Chatzkel brought is from the talmud...